# Exporting to KML from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml

I'm attempting to export a series of points that cover the continental U.S. as well as some of it's territories to KML.  When I export to KML and open it in Google Earth, the data loads in, what seems to be, an intermediate location between the regions.  However, I want the data to load/zoom in on the continental U.S.

Can I change the load point/center point in ArcGIS for Desktop before exporting to KML or would I have to change the load point within the KML code?

Answer (score 5):

You can add/append the code

```
<LookAt>
  <longitude>-121</longitude>
  <latitude>37</latitude>
  <altitude>2000</altitude>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
```

to your existing kml file to get the kml centred on a point where you choose.

There is an Example under
**Elements Specific to Placemark**

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: there is also a book available: Josie Wernecke: The KML Handbook. Addison-Wesley 2009

Answer (score 1):

Editing KML is fine, but there is a much easier way. 
You can simply right click on the folder containing the points, select properties -> view tab, and and click "snapshot current view".

This will cause the view to load at the current camera heading, altitude, etc., so you should zoom to the appropriate altitude and heading that you like first.