# How to embed images in KML balloons using FME?

Tags: fme-form

I am using FME to produce a kml file with multiple placemarks. Each placemarks corresponds to a specific feature on the ground. I am creating balloons to provide some descriptive information of the feature and I want to add a couple of images within the ballon of the feature itself.

Is this possible using FME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that. You would use the **KMLPropertySetter** transformer:

[image: KMLPropertySetter]

Because you can add HTML content there are a lot of things you can do with this. You can add links to images, and you can also link to content such as YouTube videos, tables, documents... almost anything.

If it helps you can find some learning materials for FME and KML on the [Safe Software website](http://www.safe.com/learning/training/resource-center/advanced-kml/). There is a tutorial and a training document you can work through.

There is also [a set of webinars](http://www.safe.com/learning/webinars/) available, one of which is *"How to Prepare Data for Compelling Displays in Google Earth"* and includes (I think) the YouTube embedding example.

*(**NB**: I do work for Safe Software)*

Answer (score 2):

In the  `KMLPropertySetter` http://docs.safe.com/fme/2010/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/kmlpropertysetter.htm transformer your can go to the Ballon content and open in editor (advanced) and attach your `<href>` reference image:

[image]

example:

```
href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/9428166@N03/2756609507/in/set-72157606688361690" title="Goslar Warrior (1973-74) by sandy richard, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3062/2756609507_3b598be974.jpg" width="500" height="375" alt="Goslar Warrior (1973-74)" /></a>
<br></br>Goslar Warrior (1973-74) - Sculpture # 1<br></br>Photo by Sandy Richard. <font color="#C93069">Click photo for Flickr photo page.</font><br></br>
```

This the automatic inserts the image into the balloon (some resizing might be needed)

Comment: Sorry Mark had answered this whilst I was compiling and had to go to a meeting in between posting it. Mark's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[In this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/exporting-to-kml) there is a link to a useful google doc kmlreference.
If you can find it in there you can most likely expose it in FME.
There is a nice example of probably what you are trying to do here...
[Ballon Style](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle)  (select the placemark by the island)
You will likely find MANY resources on the FMEPedia website.
Here is an example of [twitter balloons](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Geotagged-Tweets-in-KML)
And here is some more [balloon manipulation.](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Removing-Directions-from-KML-Balloons)
[add photos to your balloon](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/creating-compelling-google-earth-description-balloons/)
Jason Birch has this [blog](http://www.jasonbirch.com/nodes/2008/03/13/172/kml-goodness-from-the-fme-user-conference/#.UL97PYOZ99E) for the balloon text editor.
[FME KML 2012](http://cdn.safe.com/training/tutorials/KML-Pathway-Tutorial.pdf)
Jeffery Jenson has many  useful insights and links on this [page!](http://faculty.unlv.edu/jensen/html/FME/index.html#KMLExtendedData)
Especially the sections at descriptor balloon, and extended data.